# Is it best practice to hard-code addresses to other contracts in contract code?

Tags: solidity

This is something I've been trying to wrap my head around. I've searched for answers on the internet, but I can't really find much info for my queries.

Suppose I have a smart contract, A, that I'd like to call from another smart contract, B.

A lot of example Solidity code I've seen on the net basically sets some public/private field in A that references the real address of B, and once it gets deployed to different chains, that address is just set after B is deployed to whichever chain both will run on eventually. But then if I have a bug fix for A, and I redeploy A, it'll get a new address, so now I'll have to redeploy B with a new hardcoded address for A.

It seems pretty error prone to do this and pretty wasteful. Is there a system analogous to DNS, but for smart contracts? One thing I can think of off the top of my head is instead of hardcoding the address, you can write a smart contract C that looks sort of like this:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract C is Ownable {
  address public addressOfA;

  constructor(address _addressOfA) {
    addressOfA = _addressOfA;
  }

  function updateAddressOfA(address newAddress) public onlyOwner {
    addressOfA = newAddress
  }
}
```

Now, if I deploy a new version of A, all I have to do is issue a transaction to call `updateAddressOfA`, and contract B can instead fetch the address of A by calling `C.addressOfA()` instead.

Does this make sense? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

it's because people like the immutable part of a smart contract "written in the stone"
you know exactly what the code does and you know it won't change.
Hence the reason why it's usually not updatable